# Change placement of image in html css

Tags: html, css

i have an image on my website, i need to use `<"style=float:right">` but i have one image using it, and when i put it on it, it gets on the right side of the second image, when it should be on its left side

what i mean is on the picture, blue image is the one im trying to move, and red one is positioned. i dont know how to do that, so the red image will be at right side of blue image and be visible at all monitors and devices without scrolling
[the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaDYL.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Nobody can tell you what's wrong with code we can't see.  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.